# How to change the Ubuntu background?

Tags: desktop-background

I am new to Ubuntu, using 14.04. I was wondering if there is any way of putting up a picture or wallpaper on the Ubuntu desktop background as there is in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st Method**

Click on the gear button on the top right corner of your screen. Then click on `System Settings...` and from the window that appears click on `Appearance`. On the right in the dropdown where it reads `wallpapers` click and select `Pictures folder`. From there you can choose an image from your own pictures.

[image]

**2nd Method**

Right click on the desktop and select `Change Desktop Background`

[image]

**3rd Method**

Open a terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/your/image.png
```